# Clickable results of search into new page

Tags: php, mysql

I am working off a code that has been answered in my previous question ([Search Function results within table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19922574/search-function-results-within-table)), and I just need to add one more function to my results.

```
    $results = array();
    $i = 1;

    echo "<table border='1'>
        <tr>
        <th>Item Number</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Vendor</th>
        <th>Whole Sale Price</th>
        <th>Retail Price</th>
        <th>Profit</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        </tr>";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($searchResult)) 
    { 
        $varname = isset($_GET['ITEM_NAME']) ? $_GET['ITEM_NAME'] : FALSE;
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['ITEM_NUMBER'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td><a href='http://www.hostname.com/details.php?varname1=" . $row['ITEM_NAME'] . "'></a></td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['VENDOR'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['WHOLESALE_PRICE'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['RETAIL_PRICE'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['PROFIT'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['DESCRIPTION'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>"?>
        <?php $i++; 
    } ?>
```

What I am trying to achieve is a clickable "Item Name" which would go to a new page that has the detailed information for that product. How do I link it and what is the simplest code the details.php needs? I just need something on the details.php page that says `$row['ITEM_NUMBER']`, I will take care of the rest, as far as formatting or anything, just need the simple coding for that.

Comment: If you are trying to use `ITEM_NUMBER` as the lookup key on your details page, then why are you building the link based on `ITEM_NAME`?

Comment: Also, that while you are putting ITEM_NAME in the link destination, you aren't putting any text in the link itself so it won't show up on the page.

Comment: I don't really know how to link it. What would your suggestion be? I was just trying to make the text in that table field to be linked, thus use the `ITEM_NAME` variable in there...

Comment: OK so I updated it to `echo "<td><a href='http://www.shiroimin.com/ks/details.php?varname1=" . $row['ITEM_NAME'] . "'></a>" . $row['ITEM_NAME'] . "</td>";` to have the text, which does display the correct text, just does not hyperlink it

Comment: Ok so I did get the link to show up with `echo "<td><a href='http://www.shiroimin.com/ks/details.php?ID=" .rawurlencode($row['ITEM_ID']). "'>" . $row['ITEM_NAME'] ."</a></td>";` Now just need the details.php page to display all the information based upon the ITEM_ID from PRODUCTS table in the DB